# Заставить Input.MousePosition проходить через ноль

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Имеется код, который таскает UI объект за мышкой по клеточкам,каждая клеточка 25 юнити метров.

```
int i = (int)Math.Round(Input.mousePosition.x / 25) * 25;
discreteX = i;
int j = (int)Math.Round(Input.mousePosition.y / 25) * 25;
discreteY = j;
g.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = 
new Vector3(discreteX, discreteY);
```

Он работает хорошо, и `anchoredPosition.x` всегда проходит через 0 и затем становится +25,+50,+75 и так далее.

А проблема в том что координаты мышки не совпадают с координатами объекта `g`, , например, когда мышка болтается в нуле - т.е. в нижнем левом углу, объект `g` находится в центре экрана, где у него ноль по его `anchorPosition`

В случае же, если вместо `anchoredPositon` мы используем обычное присвоение по координатам

```
g.transform.position = new Vector3(discreteX, discreteY);
```

то позиция курсора мышки и объекта `g` совпадает, но никогда не проходит через 0 его anchoredPosition - всегда по координатам `x` вижу картину вида -35,-10,15,40 и так далее. Т.е. шаг по прежнему равен 25, но не кратен 25!

Как решить данную проблему? Либо мышку совместить с координатами `anchoredPosition`, либо обычную позицию мышки с шагом в 25 единиц держать кратным 25. Как сделать любое из этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.mousePosition` хранит свою позицию в координатах экрана, где - левый нижний угол (0,0), а правый верхний - (ширина, высота) разрешения экрана.

(0,0) у `anchorPosition` зависит от того - куда у вас установлен якорь объекта. Считаются они от родителя. Выберете объект с `RectTransform` и вы увидите, почти сразу под названием компонента, квадрат с условным обозначением якоря - у вас там будет написано `middle - middle` по граням и красный крестик с точкой в центре. Точка - условное обозначение (0,0) в координатах родителя.

Нажмите на это поле и у вас откроются возможные преднастроенные варианты привязки. Если вы выберете `bottom - left` - то (0,0) для вашего объекта станет в левом нижнем углу родителя. Если при этом размер вашего родительского объекта будет соответствовать разрешению экрана - то координатные плоскости объекта и экрана совпадут. В итоге `Input.mousePosition` и `anchorPosition` можно будет спокойно подставлять напрямую.

В тех случаях, когда размеры родителя не соответствуют экрану - можно использовать извращённую [`RectTransformUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html), которая способна превращать экранные координаты в локальные для конкретного RectTransform.

На всякий случай вот вам ещё и [статья по основам работы с RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html).

Comment: Вы молодец, я как ни старался не смог понять автора